# I made a rock paper scissors game with javascript and I'm having trouble with keeping score, I really lost

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
function computerPlay() {
    let [min, max] = [1, 3]
    let randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    if(randomNumber == 1) return 'ROCK'
    else if(randomNumber == 2) return 'PAPER'
    else return 'SCISSORS'
  }
  
  function play(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    let move = playerSelection;
      let com = computerSelection;
      if(move == 'ROCK' &&  com == 'SCISSORS') return 'ROCK beats SCISSORS';
      else if(move == 'ROCK' && com == 'PAPER') return 'PAPER beats ROCK'
      else if(move == 'SCISSORS' && com == 'ROCK') return 'ROCK beats SCISSORS'
      else if(move == 'SCISSORS' && com == 'PAPER') return 'SCISSORS beat PAPER'
      else if(move == 'PAPER' && com == 'SCISSORS') return 'SCISSORS beat PAPER'
      else if(move == 'PAPER' && com == 'ROCK') return 'PAPER beats ROCK'
      else if(move == com) return 'DRAW'
  }


let playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
let container1 = document.querySelector('.container1');
playBtn.addEventListener('click', makeContainer);






// This is the function that creates the page that needs the player's input(rock, paper or scissors)
function makeContainer() {

  container1.remove();

  let con = document.createElement('div');
  con.classList.add('container');
  let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.classList.add('one');
  h1.textContent = 'ROCK PAPER SCISSORS';
  let h12 = document.createElement('h1');
  h12.classList.add('two');
  h12.textContent = 'ROUND 1';
  let h13 = document.createElement('h1');
  h13.classList.add('three');
  h13.textContent = 'MAKE YOUR MOVE';

  let buttons = document.createElement('div');
  buttons.classList.add('buttons');

  let btn1 = document.createElement('div');
  btn1.classList.add('rock');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = 'ROCK';
  btn1.append(span);

  let btn2 = document.createElement('div');
  btn2.classList.add('paper');
  let span2 = document.createElement('span');
  span2.textContent = 'PAPER';
  btn2.append(span2);

  let btn3 = document.createElement('div');
  btn3.classList.add('scissors');
  let span3 = document.createElement('span');
  span3.textContent = 'SCISSORS';
  btn3.append(span3);

  buttons.append(btn1, btn2, btn3);

  con.append(h1, h12, h13, buttons);


  document.body.append(con);


  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
  const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
  const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');
  [rock, paper, scissors].forEach((c) => c.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target);
    containerDisappear(container, c)
  }));
}





// This function removes the makeContainer page(the one that shows rock paper scissors) and adds a transition to it
function containerDisappear(con, r) {
  let choi = r;
  con.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
  con.style.transitionDuration = '1s';
  con.style.opacity = '0';
  setTimeout(() => con.remove('container'), 1000); 
  animation(choi);
}


// This function displays the animation that pops up after the the makeContainer page has disappeared
function animation(r) {
  let choic = r;
  const waitdiv = document.createElement('div');
    waitdiv.classList.add('waitdiv');
    const div1 = document.createElement('div');
    const div2 = document.createElement('div');
    const div3 = document.createElement('div');    
    div1.classList.add('div1');
    div2.classList.add('div2');        
    div3.classList.add('div3');
    div1.textContent = 'ROCK...';
    div2.textContent = 'PAPER...';
    div3.textContent = 'SCISSORS...';
    waitdiv.append(div1, div2, div3);
    document.body.append(waitdiv);    
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        div1.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        div1.style.transitionDuration = '.6s';
        div1.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 600);
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        div2.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        div2.style.transitionDuration = '.6s';
        div2.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 1200);
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        div3.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        div3.style.transitionDuration = '.6s';
        div3.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 1800); 
    
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        waitdiv.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        waitdiv.style.transitionDuration = '.3s';
        waitdiv.style.opacity = '0';
        waitdiv.remove();
    }, 2400);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      results(choic)
    }, 2400);
}



// This function displays the player's move vs the computer's move and then displays information about who lost
/* Theres a 0:1 right at the bottom of this page, it's static, it doesn't update after each move, it's actually one of the things I'm
struggling with */
function results(c) {
  const cShoot = document.createElement('div');
    cShoot.classList.add('container-shoot');
    const shoot = document.createElement('h1');
    shoot.classList.add('shoot');
    const round = document.createElement('h1');
    round.classList.add('round');
    const versus = document.createElement('div');
    versus.classList.add('versus');
    const v = document.createElement('div');
    v.classList.add('v');
    const h6 = document.createElement('h6');
    const choice = document.createElement('div');
    choice.classList.add('choice');
    const vs = document.createElement('div');
    vs.classList.add('v');
    const v2 = document.createElement('div');
    v2.classList.add('v');
    const choice2 = document.createElement('div');
    choice2.classList.add('choice');
    const h62 = document.createElement('h6');
  
    // ----------------second part---------------------------------------
    const info = document.createElement('div');
    info.classList.add('info');
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    const h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
  
  
    // ---------------------third part------------------------------------
    const score = document.createElement('div');
    score.classList.add('score');
    const span2 = document.createElement('span');
    span2.classList.add('player');
    const span3 = document.createElement('span');
    span3.classList.add('colon');
    const span4 = document.createElement('span');
    span4.classList.add('com');


    // ---------------------time to append stuff--------------------------------------------
    cShoot.append(shoot, round, versus, info, score);
    versus.append(v, vs, v2);
    v.append(h6, choice);
    vs.textContent = 'VS';
    v2.append(choice2, h62);
    info.append(h2, h3);
    h3.append(span);
    span2.textContent = '0';
    span3.textContent = ':';
    span4.textContent = '1';
    score.append(span2, span3, span4);
  
    // ----------------adding text--------------------------------------------
    shoot.textContent = 'SHOOT!!!';
    round.textContent = 'ROUND 1';
    h6.textContent = 'YOU';
    choice.textContent = (c.classList.value == 'rock') ? 'ROCK' :
    c.classList.value == 'paper' ? 'PAPER' : 
    c.classList.value == 'scissors' ? 'SCISSORS' : null;
    vs.textContent = 'VS';
    choice2.textContent = computerPlay();
    h62.textContent = 'COM';
    h2.textContent = play(choice.textContent, choice2.textContent);
    span.textContent = s();
    if(span.textContent == 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND') span.style.color = 'green';
    else span.style.color = 'red'

    // -------------------------function-------------------------------------------------
    function s() {
      if(choice.textContent == 'ROCK' && choice2.textContent == 'SCISSORS') {
        return 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'ROCK' && choice2.textContent == 'PAPER') {
        return 'YOU LOSE THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'SCISSORS' && choice2.textContent == 'ROCK') {
        return 'YOU LOSE THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'SCISSORS' && choice2.textContent == 'PAPER') {
        return 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'PAPER' && choice2.textContent == 'SCISSORS') {
        return 'YOU LOSE THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'PAPER' && choice2.textContent == 'ROCK') {
        return 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND'
      }
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------


    document.body.append(cShoot);
    // cShoot is the first variable that was created inside this function, it's the div tha holds everything on this page


}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 30px;
}

.rock {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.05s;
}

.rock:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.paper {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.05s;
}

.paper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.scissors {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.05s;
}

.scissors:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

span {
    font-size: 22px;
}


.one {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}

.two {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
}

.three {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.waitdiv {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.div1 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.div2 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.div3 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.container-shoot {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.shoot {
    font-size: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

.round {
    position: relative;
    top: 55px;
}

.versus {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 80%;
}

.v {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.choice {
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    /* font-size: 30px; */
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -70px);
}

.info h3 span {
    color: white;
}

.score {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -20px); 
}

.score span {
    font-size: 70px;
}

.container1 {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.play-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 15px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
}

.next {
    border-radius: 17px;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
        <button class="play-btn">PLAY</button>
    </div>
```

I made a rock paper scissors game with javascript and I'm having trouble with keeping score.
I need a way to keep track of who is winning between the player and the computer, that score should be displayed right at the bottom of the page.
If you run the whole code(html, css and javascript), you will see this example right at the bottom of the last page
I encourage you to please run the whole code

Here's my HTML file:

```
<div class="container1"><button class="play-btn">PLAY</button></div>
```

Here's the code i wrote in my JAVASCRIPT file:

```
function computerPlay() {
let [min, max] = [1, 3]
let randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
if(randomNumber == 1) return 'ROCK'
else if(randomNumber == 2) return 'PAPER'
else return 'SCISSORS'
```

}

```
function play(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
let move = playerSelection;
  let com = computerSelection;
  if(move == 'ROCK' && com == 'SCISSORS') return 'ROCK beats SCISSORS';
  else if(move == 'ROCK' && com == 'PAPER') return 'PAPER beats ROCK'
  else if(move == 'SCISSORS' && com == 'ROCK') return 'ROCK beats SCISSORS'
  else if(move == 'SCISSORS' && com == 'PAPER') return 'SCISSORS beat PAPER'
  else if(move == 'PAPER' && com == 'SCISSORS') return 'SCISSORS beat PAPER'
  else if(move == 'PAPER' && com == 'ROCK') return 'PAPER beats ROCK'
  else if(move == com) return 'DRAW'
```

}

```
let arr = [];

let playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
let container1 = document.querySelector('.container1');
playBtn.addEventListener('click', makeContainer);
```

This is the function that creates the page that needs the player's input(rock, paper or scissors)

```
function makeContainer() {

  container1.remove();

  let con = document.createElement('div');
  con.classList.add('container');
  let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.classList.add('one');
  h1.textContent = 'ROCK PAPER SCISSORS';
  let h12 = document.createElement('h1');
  h12.classList.add('two');
  h12.textContent = 'ROUND 1';
  let h13 = document.createElement('h1');
  h13.classList.add('three');
  h13.textContent = 'MAKE YOUR MOVE';

  let buttons = document.createElement('div');
  buttons.classList.add('buttons');

  let btn1 = document.createElement('div');
  btn1.classList.add('rock');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = 'ROCK';
  btn1.append(span);

  let btn2 = document.createElement('div');
  btn2.classList.add('paper');
  let span2 = document.createElement('span');
  span2.textContent = 'PAPER';
  btn2.append(span2);

  let btn3 = document.createElement('div');
  btn3.classList.add('scissors');
  let span3 = document.createElement('span');
  span3.textContent = 'SCISSORS';
  btn3.append(span3);

  buttons.append(btn1, btn2, btn3);

  con.append(h1, h12, h13, buttons);


  document.body.append(con);


  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
  const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
  const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');
  [rock, paper, scissors].forEach((c) => c.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target);
    containerDisappear(container, c)
  }));
}
```

This function removes the makeContainer page(the one that shows rock paper scissors) and adds a transition to it

```
function containerDisappear(con, r) {
  let choi = r;
  con.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
  con.style.transitionDuration = '1s';
  con.style.opacity = '0';
  setTimeout(() => con.remove('container'), 1000); 
  animation(choi);
}
```

This function displays the animation that pops up after the the makeContainer page has disappeared

```
 function animation(r) {
  let choic = r;
  const waitdiv = document.createElement('div');
    waitdiv.classList.add('waitdiv');
    const div1 = document.createElement('div');
    const div2 = document.createElement('div');
    const div3 = document.createElement('div');    
    div1.classList.add('div1');
    div2.classList.add('div2');        
    div3.classList.add('div3');
    div1.textContent = 'ROCK...';
    div2.textContent = 'PAPER...';
    div3.textContent = 'SCISSORS...';
    waitdiv.append(div1, div2, div3);
    document.body.append(waitdiv);    
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        div1.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        div1.style.transitionDuration = '.6s';
        div1.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 600);
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        div2.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        div2.style.transitionDuration = '.6s';
        div2.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 1200);
  
    setTimeout(() => {
        div3.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        div3.style.transitionDuration = '.6s';
        div3.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 1800); 
    
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        waitdiv.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        waitdiv.style.transitionDuration = '.3s';
        waitdiv.style.opacity = '0';
        waitdiv.remove();
    }, 2400);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      results(choic)
    }, 2400);
}
```

This function displays the player's move vs the computer's move and then displays information about who lost
Theres a 0:1 right at the bottom of this page, it's static, it doesn't update after each move, it's actually one of the things I'm struggling with

```
function results(c) {
  const cShoot = document.createElement('div');
    cShoot.classList.add('container-shoot');
    const shoot = document.createElement('h1');
    shoot.classList.add('shoot');
    const round = document.createElement('h1');
    round.classList.add('round');
    const versus = document.createElement('div');
    versus.classList.add('versus');
    const v = document.createElement('div');
    v.classList.add('v');
    const h6 = document.createElement('h6');
    const choice = document.createElement('div');
    choice.classList.add('choice');
    const vs = document.createElement('div');
    vs.classList.add('v');
    const v2 = document.createElement('div');
    v2.classList.add('v');
    const choice2 = document.createElement('div');
    choice2.classList.add('choice');
    const h62 = document.createElement('h6');
  
    // ----------------second part---------------------------------------
    const info = document.createElement('div');
    info.classList.add('info');
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    const h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
  
  
    // ---------------------third part------------------------------------
    const score = document.createElement('div');
    score.classList.add('score');
    const span2 = document.createElement('span');
    span2.classList.add('player');
    const span3 = document.createElement('span');
    span3.classList.add('colon');
    const span4 = document.createElement('span');
    span4.classList.add('com');


    // ---------------------time to append stuff--------------------------------------------
    cShoot.append(shoot, round, versus, info, score);
    versus.append(v, vs, v2);
    v.append(h6, choice);
    vs.textContent = 'VS';
    v2.append(choice2, h62);
    info.append(h2, h3);
    h3.append(span);
    span2.textContent = '0';
    span3.textContent = ':';
    span4.textContent = '1';
    score.append(span2, span3, span4);
  
    // ----------------adding text--------------------------------------------
    shoot.textContent = 'SHOOT!!!';
    round.textContent = 'ROUND 1';
    h6.textContent = 'YOU';
    choice.textContent = (c.classList.value == 'rock') ? 'ROCK' :
    c.classList.value == 'paper' ? 'PAPER' : 
    c.classList.value == 'scissors' ? 'SCISSORS' : null;
    vs.textContent = 'VS';
    choice2.textContent = computerPlay();
    h62.textContent = 'COM';
    h2.textContent = play(choice.textContent, choice2.textContent);
    span.textContent = s();
    if(span.textContent == 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND') span.style.color = 'green';
    else span.style.color = 'red'

    // -------------------------function-------------------------------------------------
    function s() {
      if(choice.textContent == 'ROCK' && choice2.textContent == 'SCISSORS') {
        return 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'ROCK' && choice2.textContent == 'PAPER') {
        return 'YOU LOSE THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'SCISSORS' && choice2.textContent == 'ROCK') {
        return 'YOU LOSE THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'SCISSORS' && choice2.textContent == 'PAPER') {
        return 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'PAPER' && choice2.textContent == 'SCISSORS') {
        return 'YOU LOSE THIS ROUND'
      }
      else if(choice.textContent == 'PAPER' && choice2.textContent == 'ROCK') {
        return 'YOU WIN THIS ROUND'
      }
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------


    document.body.append(cShoot);
    // cShoot is the first variable that was created inside this function, it's the div tha holds everything on this page


}
```

Here's my css file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 30px;
}

.rock {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.05s;
}

.rock:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.paper {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.05s;
}

.paper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.scissors {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.05s;
}

.scissors:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

span {
    font-size: 22px;
}


.one {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}

.two {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
}

.three {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.waitdiv {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.div1 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.div2 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.div3 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.container-shoot {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.shoot {
    font-size: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

.round {
    position: relative;
    top: 55px;
}

.versus {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 80%;
}

.v {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.choice {
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    /* font-size: 30px; */
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -70px);
}

.info h3 span {
    color: white;
}

.score {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -20px); 
}

.score span {
    font-size: 70px;
}

.container1 {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.play-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 15px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
}

.next {
    border-radius: 17px;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    color: black;

}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your code to make it runnable? You can even use the live snippet thing.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that you can reduce this very long post to something simpler, and you should explain the problem _before_ dumping code so we know what we're looking at. See [ask].

Comment: I could help you write a completely functional roshambo game with a fraction of what you have posted (I believe you posted it twice?), but to help you fix that monstrosity, would be a waste of time for us and yourself. You should really start all over again. Apologies  for being blunt.

Comment: @zer00ne yeah you're right about building a fully functional game with a fraction of the code, and I did that before, but the thing is I don't want to build something boring, I want to add some animations, something the player can interact with. That's why the code is so long.

Comment: I'm still a newbie to coding by the way

Comment: Feel free to ask me questions so I can explain what I did where.

Comment: @AmogelangChaane hopefully this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72969504/2813224) should help

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

> *"...I'm having trouble with keeping score. I need a way to keep track of who is winning between the player and the computer,..."*

I cannot be specifically say what the problem is in OP (**O**riginal **P**ost) code because it's too bloated. Instead of combing through 200 lines and ending up rewriting 80% of the code, I have made a roshambo game that behaves and appears simular to the OP code (see **Example B**).

### Solutions

**`<form>` & Form Controls**

The best HTML layout for simple games is a `<form>` and [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content). The [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) and [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interfaces allow us to use a terse and versatile syntax (see **Figure IA** and **Figure IB**)

**Figure IA** - Simple HTML layout of `<form>` and form controls

```html
<form id='contacts'>
  <fieldset name='group'>
    <label>First Name:
      <input id='firstname' value='zer0'>
    </label>
    <label>Last Name:
      <input id='lastname' value='0ne'>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name='group'>
    <output id='fullname'></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name='group'>
    <label>Phone: <input id='phone' type='tel'></label>
    <button type='reset'>Reset</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Figure IB** - A comparison between DOM interfaces

| Objective | HTMLFormElement | Common DOM Methods |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `<form>` | `const C = document.forms.contacts` | `const C = document.getElementById('contacts')` |
| All form controls | `const all = C.elements` | `const all = C.querySelectorAll('fieldset, input, button')` |
| All `<fieldset>`s | `const sets = all.group` | `const sets = C.querySelectorAll('fieldset')` |
| Get the value of `<input id='phone'>` | `let cell = all.phone.value` | `let cell = C.querySelector('#phone').value` |

Also see [Form Properties and Methods](https://javascript.info/form-elements)

**Special Events**

There are also events that are made exclusively for `<form>`s and form controls (see **Figure II**). Specialized behavior allows us to write less and control which elements can react and which elements to exclude. Moreover, it's important to know how to [delegate events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) by binding events to a parent or ancestor element of multiple origin elements (buttons, inputs, etc) and writing  event handlers that target specific elements.

**Figure II** - Special Events

| Event | Tags | Trigger | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [submit](https://javascript.info/forms-submit) | `<form>` | 1. User is focused on a text field and hits the <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> key. 2. User clicks a `<button>`, `<input type='submit'>`, or `<input type='image'>`. 3. `.submit()` method. | `<form>` will send the values of all form controls<sup>❉</sup> that have a `[name]` attribute to a server. If there is no server then it will return a blank page. |
| [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset_event) | `<form>` | 1. User clicks a button with `type="reset"` 2. `.reset()` method | All form control values entered by the user are removed |
| [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) | `<form>` and form controls<sup>❉</sup> | User enters data or selects a value on/from a form control then loses focus |  |
| [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) | `<form>` and form controls<sup>❉</sup> | User enters data or selects a value on/from a form control |  |

<sup>✳ buttons: `<button>` with or without `type`: `"button"`, `"submit"`, `"reset"`, and `<input>` with one of the following `type`: `"button"`, `"submit"`, `"reset"`, `"image"`</sup>
<sup>❉ buttons<sup>✳</sup> and `<output>` are excluded</sup>

**Incrementing `.value` Property and Closures** - See **Example A**

1. Define a variable at initial number (usually 0) ***outside*** of any function.
2. Reference a form control that has or can have a `.value` property.
3. Increment the variable from #1.
4. Assign the value of the variable from #1 to the referenced form control from #2

In #1 we define a variable (it can be a number, an index of an array or an object value from a property, etc) outside of the function because once a function ends, everything within is garbage collected, so the value must be outside but within scope of the function, see [Closures](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-closure/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20closure%20is,the%20lexical%20scoping%20works%20first).

**Details are commented in both Example A and Example B**

### Example A

```js
// Define values outside of function #1
const coin = {
  sides: ['https://i.ibb.co/QvT4L5k/heads.png', 'https://i.ibb.co/C6Y3HKd/tails.png'],
  heads: 0,
  tails: 0
};
// Reference the <form>
const UI = document.forms.toss;
// Prevent normal <form> behavior during a submit event
UI.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault();
// Bind <form> to click event
UI.onclick = flipCoin;
// Event handler passes Event Object by default
function flipCoin(e) {
  // Get a random number between 0 and 1
  let side = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1; // 0 or 1
  // Reference the element the user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  /*
  If the user clicked input#flip...
  ...change it's src...
  ...increment coin = {heads or tails}...
  ...assign heads/tails value of {coin} to the <output>s
  */
  if (clk.id === 'flip') {
    clk.src = coin.sides[side];
    side === 0 ? coin.heads += 1 : coin.tails += 1;
    IO.heads.value = coin.heads;
    IO.tails.value = coin.tails;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='toss'>
  <input id='flip' src='https://i.ibb.co/QvT4L5k/heads.png' type='image'><br> Heads: <output id='heads'></output><br> Tails: <output id='tails'></output>
</form>
```

### Example B

```js
// Reference <form>
const game = document.forms.roshambo;
// Collect all <dialog> into an array
const dialogs = [...document.querySelectorAll('dialog')];
// Define an object outside of functions to keep track of the score
const score = {
  turn: 0,
  wins: 0,
  lost: 0,
  draw: 0
};
/*
Bind the "DOMContentLoaded" event to the document
When all DOM content is loaded...
...close all <dialog>s...
...open the first <dialog>
*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  dialogs.forEach(d => d.close());
  dialogs[0].showModal();
})
// Bind "reset" event to <form>
game.onreset = phase0;
// Bind "click" event to <form>
game.onclick = choice;
// Event handler passes Event Object by default
function choice(event) {
  // Reference the tag the user clicked
  const clicked = event.target;
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  /*
  If the user clicked a [name="clear"]...
  ...reset all of {score}'s properties to 0...
  ...trigger a "reset" event on <form>
  */
  if (clicked.name === 'clear') {
    for (let prop in score) {
      score[prop] = 0;
    }
    this.reset();
  }
  /*
  If the user clicked a [name="rps"]...
  ...close all <dialog>...
  ...open the third <dialog>...
  ...define an array -
     index 0 is the value of the clicked <button> converted into a number
     index 1 is the result of rand()
     [(0-2), (0-2)]...
  ...call phase2() passing the array and a reference to all form controls
  */
  if (clicked.name === 'rps') {
    dialogs.forEach(d => d.close());
    dialogs[2].showModal();
    let RPS = [parseInt(clicked.value), rand()];
    phase2(RPS, IO);
  }
}
// Event handler passes the Event Object by default
function phase0(event) {
  // Prevent the <form> from clearing out all of the <output>
  event.preventDefault();
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  // Close all <dialog>s
  dialogs.forEach(d => d.close());
  // Open the second <dialog>
  dialogs[1].showModal();
  // Increment score: {turn}
  score.turn += 1;
  // call phase1() passing the reference to all form controls
  phase1(IO);
}
// Pass the reference to all form controls
function phase1(IO) {
  // Reference all form controls in fieldset#choices
  const io = IO.choices.elements;
  // Update all <output> under fieldset#choices
  io.round.value = score.turn;
  io.wins.value = score.wins;
  io.lost.value = score.lost;
  io.draw.value = score.draw;
}
// Pass the array of numbers and the reference to all form controls
function phase2(RPS, IO) {
  // Define an array of strings 
  const text = ['ROCK..., ', 'PAPER..., ', 'SCISSORS... '];
  // Define a number that will be the base amount of ms for timeouts
  let time = 600;
  // Call animate() passing array, a selector of tag to append to, and time
  animate(text, '#animation h1', time);
  // Call phase3() passing what phase2() passed on the calculated time
  setTimeout(() => {
    phase3(RPS, IO);
  }, (text.length + 4) * time);
}
// Pass array and reference
function phase3(RPS, IO) {
  // Close all <dialog>s
  dialogs.forEach(d => d.close());
  // Open the fourth <dialog>
  dialogs[3].showModal();
  // Call outcome() passing the array and reference
  outcome(RPS, IO);
}
// Displays 'ROCK..., ', 'PAPER..., ', 'SCISSORS... ' at timed intervals
function delay(array, title, time) {
  array.forEach((segment, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const tag = document.createElement('b');
      tag.textContent = segment;
      tag.className = 'fadeIn';
      title.append(tag);
    }, index * time);
  });
}
// Runs delay() and animates "GO!"
function animate(array, selector, time = 1000) {
  const title = document.querySelector(selector);
  delay(array, title, time);
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.replaceChildren();
    title.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<b class='zoom'>GO!</b>`);
  }, (array.length + 1) * time);
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.className = 'fadeOut';
    title.replaceChildren();
  }, (array.length + 3) * time);
  title.className = '';
}
// Returns a random number in the range of 0-2
function rand() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
}
// Pass the numbers derived from choice(e)
function play(pick, comp) {
  // This is a ternary expression - an abbreviated if/else statement
  return pick === comp // if user's num equals cpu's num
    ? 0 // return 0
    : comp === pick - 1 // if cpu's num is 1 less than user's num 
    ? 1 // return 1
    : comp === 2 && pick === 0 // if cpu num is 2 AND user's num is 0
    ? 1 // return 1
    : -1; // else return -1
}
// Pass the array and reference
function outcome(RPS, IO) {
  // Define an array of RPS
  const played = [' Rock', ' Paper', '✂️ Scissors'];
  // Reference all form controls under fieldset#outcome
  const io = IO.outcome.elements;
  // Get the return of play() passing the two numbers of the given array
  let wld = play(RPS[0], RPS[1]);
  // Assign values to the <output>s
  io.you.value = played[RPS[0]];
  io.cpu.value = played[RPS[1]];
  io.round.value = score.turn;
  io.draw.value = score.draw;
  io.wins.value = score.wins;
  io.lost.value = score.lost;
  // Determine what will be displayed by the return of play()
  switch (wld) {
    case 0:
      score.draw += 1;
      io.draw.value = score.draw;
      io.message.value = "It's a Draw";
      io.vs.value = "Ties with";
      break;
    case 1:
      score.wins += 1;
      io.wins.value = score.wins;
      io.message.value = "You Win";
      io.vs.value = "Beats";
      break;
    case -1:
      score.lost += 1;
      io.lost.value = score.lost;
      io.message.value = "You Lose";
      io.vs.value = "is Beaten by";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');
@keyframes click {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  font: 300 4vmin/1 Oswald;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: #333;
}

.phase {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  min-width: 70vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-color: transparent;
}

legend {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-left: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

.score {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 100%;
}

output,
b {
  display: inline-block;
}

output::after {
  content: attr(value);
}

.wins::before {
  content: 'Won ';
}

.lost::before {
  content: 'Lost ';
}

.draw::before {
  content: 'Draw ';
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid red;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: red;
}

button:active {
  animation: click 0.3s forwards;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 0.6s ease-out;
}

.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut 0.6s ease-in;
}

.zoom {
  animation: zoom 0.5s ease-out forwards;
}

.number {
  font-family: Consolas;
}
```

```html
<form id="roshambo">

  <dialog>
    <fieldset id='start' class='phase'>
      <button name='continue' type="reset">Play</button>
    </fieldset>
  </dialog>

  <dialog>
    <fieldset id='choices' class='phase'>
      <legend>
        <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>
        <h2>Round <output name='round' class='number'></output>
        </h2>
        <h3>Make Your Move</h3>
        <h3 class='score'>
          <b class='wins'>
            <output name='wins' class='number'></output>
          </b>
          <b class='lost'>
            <output name='lost' class='number'></output>
          </b>
          <b class='draw'>
            <output name='draw' class='number'></output>
          </b>
        </h3>
      </legend>
      <fieldset class='buttons'>
        <button name='rps' value='0' type='button'> Rock</button>
        <button name='rps' value='1' type='button'> Paper</button>
        <button name='rps' value='2' type='button'>✂️ Scissors</button>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </dialog>

  <dialog>
    <fieldset id='animation' class='phase'>
      <legend>
        <h1></h1>
      </legend>
    </fieldset>
  </dialog>

  <dialog>
    <fieldset id='outcome' class='phase'>
      <legend>
        <h1><output id='message'></output></h1>
        <h2>Round <output name='round' class='number'></output></h2>
        <h3>Your
          <output id='you'></output>
          <output id='vs'></output> Your Opponent's
          <output id='cpu'></output>
        </h3>
        <h3 class='score'>
          <b class='wins'>
            <output name='wins' class='number'></output>
          </b>
          <b class='lost'>
            <output name='lost' class='number'></output>
          </b>
          <b class='draw'>
            <output name='draw' class='number'></output>
          </b>
        </h3>
      </legend>

      <fieldset class='buttons'>
        <button name='continue' type='reset'>Continue</button>
        <button name='clear' type='reset'>Clear</button>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </dialog>

</form>
```